# Delay in first website opening - Downloading proxy script

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

`Chrome` starts on normal speed, but unable to open any websites. I get

> Downloading proxy script...

message on status bar for 15-20 seconds. After that page is loaded. I use `Chrome 64.0.3282.186` and there are `uBlock Origin`, `Adobe Acrobat` and `Adblock Plus` installed on it.

Comment: You have a proxy configured?

Comment: @TarunLalwani : No.

Comment: Which OS are you using Chrome on? You should update your question with the OS details as well and also a image showing the proxy settings of chrome

Comment: @TarunLalwani : I use Windows 10, but there isn't proxy configured, it is direct connection.

Comment: Do you have both Wifi and LAN activated by any chance?

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Yes, both are activated.

Comment: can you just keep one active and other disabled and then try if you face the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166611/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-plaidshirt).

Comment: Any update on this? Just using one interface, does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been described in below

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770201

If you read the last comment

> Discovered a work-around, which may be helpful in diagnosing the issue.
>
> I disable the Wi-Fi adapter. (I'm on a laptop with both Wi-Fi and LAN.)
>
> That's it - the "proxy script" prompt immediately disappears, as Chrome connects via the LAN instead.
>
> Once it's connected, I can re-enable the Wi-Fi and everything is back to normal.

Since you have a confirmed that you use both Wifi and LAN, I assume this is the issue you are facing and it is known chrome bug.

Some other threads you might want to follow are below

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=558754

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794458

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=816532

Comment: Wifi is disabled, when wired connection is active, but problem is still persists.

Answer (score 2):

If your client proxy setting for the browser is set to ‘automatic’ then your browser will try http://wpad/proxy.pac to find a javascript that tells it what to do. If it is not available, your observation might be explained. To avoid this set the proxy to ‘direct connection’ or adjust the proxy.pac file on the proxy.

Comment: I tried that on my Mac and it works without taking a sec, this should initially be a comment and if confirmed by OP should be logged as an answer

Comment: “Works on my computer.” does not solve someone else’s problem very well. StackExchange’s algorithms will resolve the merit of my answer despite eager moderation.